# Existe alguma razão técnica para o padrão Observer ou assemelhandos não ser usado de forma independente ao objeto observado?

Tags: design-pattern, engenharia-de-software, observer-pattern

Muitas vezes usamos coisas que nem pensamos bem porque é assim.

Eu não gosto de colocar penduricalhos de mecanismo em objeto que é de domínio específico.

Se eu tenho um controle de tela ou um cliente que tem alguma ação que dispara um evento o meu normal é usar alguma forma de evento onde o objeto tem uma lista de assinantes que obviamente vai crescendo conforme vai tendo objetos interessados (observadores) em alguma mudança de estado ou comportamento que esse objeto observado se dispõe avisar que ocorreu, está ocorrendo ou irá ocorrer. O mecanismo de controle fica nesse objeto e tem o custo nele.

Fiquei pensando se não é mais interessante ter um objeto de observação separado, aí esse objeto que era observado informa ao objeto de observação que ele tem eventos disponíveis e os objetos observadores assinam esses eventos desejados. Todo esse objeto é responsável pelo mecanismo de observação e os objetos que se comunicam não possuem mecanismos próprios reduzindo sua responsabilidade, aparentemente melhorando a coesão e acoplamento.

Me preocupo principalmente com o o objeto carregar estado que não faz parte do domínio dele. Sei que é preciosismo em muitos casos e não devo me preocupar demais com isso. Mas ainda fica a dúvida se do ponto de vista estrito da engenharia faz sentido fazer algo assim.

Não quero saber qual é o melhor, mas se eu estou vendo o quadro geral de forma adequada ou perdi alguma coisa importante.

Exemplo apenas ilustrativo bem simplificado e ingenuamente em pseudocódigo:

```
class Score
    value = 0
    Increase() {
        value++
        Changed(this)
    }
    Score() {
        RegisterEvent(this, Increase)
    }
    ~Score() {
        UnregisterEvent(this, Increase)
    }

class Observation {
    observables[] = new[]
    RegisterEvent(obj, method) {
        observables[obj << ptrLength + method] = new[]
    }
    UnregisterEvent(obj, method) {
        observables[obj << ptrLength + method] = null
    }
    SubscribeEvent(obj, method, action) {
        observables[obj << ptrLength + method] += action
    UnsubscribeEvent(obj, method, action) {
        observables[obj << ptrLength + method] -= action
    }
}
class App {
    static player1 = new Score()
    static player2 = new Score()
}
class Screen {
    Screen() {
        SubscribeEvent(player1, Score.Increase, PaintScore1) {
        SubscribeEvent(player2, Score.Increase, PaintScore2) {
    }
    ~Screen() {
        UnsubscribeEvent(player1, Score.Increase, PaintScore1) {
        UnsubscribeEvent(player2, Score.Increase, PaintScore2) {
    }
    PaintScore1(obj) { ... }
    PaintScore2(obj) { ... }
}
class Fire {
    ...
    Reached(player) {
        (player == 1 ? player1 : player2).Increase()
    }
}
```

Isto seria a mesma coisa que o padrão Mediator? Se for, o Mediator seria um substituto para o Observer? Ou eles servem para propósitos diferentes. Com advento do Mediator o Observer seria obsoleto? Ou eles se complementam? Ou seria errado eles se complementarem?

Isto seria o Event Aggregator? E esta só uma is uma da inúmeras coisas que eu achei que inventei? Dammit Fowler! :P

Comment: Não sei se entendi muito bem, a proposta que você descreveu tem uma certa semelhança com o Mediator Pattern ou a combinação de Mediator + Observer. Caso eu não tenha entendido direito, pode me explicar a diferênça entre o que você está propondo e que o Mediator Pattern não resolva?

Comment: @TomMelo editei, veja se ajuda responder. Eu já vi o Mediator, mas ainda não tenho experiência com ele. De fato a ideia veio vendo uma implementação dele, mas não vi eventos. Aí a dúvida pode ser justamente o que você quer saber :)

Comment: Ah, agora ficou mais claro! Outra coisa que lembra também é o Event Aggregator.

Comment: @TomMelo se achar que rola uma resposta colocando essas coisas...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Existe alguma razão técnica para o padrão Observer ou assemelhandos não ser usado de forma independente ao objeto observado?

Do ponto de vista de coesão e acoplamento, tanto o **Subject** (Observado) quanto os **Observers** (Observadores) são independentes, ou seja, o funcionamento e a responsabilidade de um "subject" não depende de observers e, não importa qual o tipo e especialização dos objetos envolvidos, todos só precisam respeitar um "contrato"(interface) por exemplo.

Exemplo ilustrativo:

Interface `Observer`

```
public interface Observer {

    void onStateChanged(String attribute, Object oldValue, Object newValue);    
}
```

Interface `Subject`

```
public interface Subject {

    void addObserver(Observer observer);

    void removeObserver(Observer observer); 
}
```

Uma classe "Observable"

```
public class Bird implements Subject {

    private List<Observer> observers = new ArrayList<>();
    private boolean flying;

    public boolean isFlying() {
        return flying;
    }

    public void setFlying(boolean flying) {
        boolean oldValue = this.flying;
        this.flying = flying;
        notifyObservers("flying", oldValue, this.flying);
    }

    @Override
    public void addObserver(Observer observer) {
        observers.add(observer);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeObserver(Observer observer) {
        observers.remove(observer);     
    }

    private void notifyObservers(String attribute, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
        observers.forEach(o -> o.onStateChanged(attribute, oldValue, newValue));
    }       
}
```

Uma classe "Observer"

```
public class BirdObserver implements Observer {

    @Override
    public void onStateChanged(String attribute, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
        System.out.println(String.format("%s %s %s", attribute, oldValue, newValue));       
    }
}
```

Note que, mesmo com uma relação 1xN, o custo (Pub/Sub) é bem baixo, não vejo o mecanismo de pub/sub fora do escopo de um objeto "Observable".

Portanto, não acredito que exista uma razão técnica para isso não acontecer de forma separada no Observer Pattern.

Agora, a sua proposta tem uma certa semelhança com outros dois patterns:

- [Mediator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern)
- [Event Aggregator](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventAggregator.html)

Então, por que não aplica-los em todos os casos onde é necessário um mecanismo de pub/sub?

Como eu disse anteriormente, o custo do Observer não tem impacto significativo na coesão e acoplamento, se você tem uma aplicação simples que precisa de pub/sub, esse pattern resolve sem problemas.

Agora, imagine uma aplicação que possua mais de 100 Observables(com múltiplos tipos de eventos) e mais de 100 Observers. Pra deixar um pouco mais complexo imagine que alguns desses objetos necessitem de uma noção de estados com relação NxN. Seria um pouco complexo gerenciar isso apenas com o Observer. Nesse caso poderia entrar o papel de um "centralizador" pra gerenciar a troca de mensagens entre todos, e é aí que entra o Mediator ou Event Aggregator.

Portanto,

> Isto seria a mesma coisa que o padrão Mediator?

Proposta bem parecida.

> Se for, o Mediator seria um substituto para o Observer? Ou eles servem para propósitos diferentes.

Não, um não substitui o outro. Eles possuem semelhanças em facilitar a comunicação entre objetos.

> Com advento do Mediator o Observer seria obsoleto? Ou eles se complementam? Ou seria errado eles se complementarem?

Também não, o mediator não torna o observer obsoleto. Podem ser usados de forma independente ou podem se complementar, depende do cenário aplicado.

> Isto seria o Event Aggregator?

É um pouco parecido também.

> E esta só mais uma das inúmeras coisas que eu achei que inventei?

Aparentemente sim, sorry. =P

Comment: Só hoje consegui ler, muito boa! É que parecido não é a mesma coisa. Ainda preciso colocar em prática pra ver se não é algo diferente, tem padrão que parece idêntico, mas tem um detalhe que faz ele ser diferente. Eu não sei se essa estória de "não tem impacto significativo no coesão", usar `double` para valor monetário também não tem, mas erro é erro. Eu estou me convencendo que adotaram uma estratégia errada ante, e já vi muita reclamação sobre o Observer, acho que até respondi algo sobre isso. Eu sou pragmático, acho ok fazer certas coisas que não são ideais,mas estritamente me parece errado